# adding an image to Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the Facebook like button installed and working. I want to add an image that posts to the users wall. How can I do this?

```
<fb:like send="true" width="200" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

EDIT:

Added og tag

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.com/image.gif" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add open graph meta property tags with link to your image. (something like: `<meta property="og:image" content="http://linktoyourimage.jpg" />`)

You can read everything about this: http://www.ogp.me/.

Best

Comment: I just did this a few minutes ago, and it still is not working. Sample code posted above

Comment: Nevermind, it's working. Facebook hadn't scraped my site. Thanks

Comment: Facebook has its own cache so you can't see the changes immediately. Pull your URL through facebook debugger: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug , and see if the image is here or not. If it is here, just wait for FAcebook to refresh its cache.